# Error : "The codec cannot use the type of stream provided" while reading a .tiff File

Tags: c#, .net, image, inputstream, tiff

I am getting the above error when I try to read a .tif image with TiffBitmapDecoder. The code I am using is

```
using (Stream stream = new FileStream(filepath,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read,FileShare.Read))
            {
                TiffBitmapDecoder decoder = new TiffBitmapDecoder(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache, BitmapCacheOption.None);

                BitmapSource bitmapsource = decoder.Frames[0];
            }
```

In case if anyone faced similar Issue ans solved it. please so share some thought on it.

Comment: what  error are you getting?

Comment: "The codec cannot use the type of stream provided" this is the error I am getting

Comment: Can you ensure the file is actually of type .tiff and not something else sometimes a file can be manually renamed to change the extensions.

Comment: @makot: I am getting the same error now on same line Tiffbitmapdecoder. Please help me. Whatdid you do to resolve that?

Comment: TIFF is an acronym for Thousands of Incompatible File Formats.  If you are sure this is actually a tiff file and not just a file with a wrong filename extension and have no control over the app that creates the file then you need to go shopping, Lead Tools is the thousand pound gorilla in that business segment.

Comment: @HansPassant: lol sorry I didn't quite get what you saying, I understood partially. Well I just renamed a jpeg to tiff :) :) That didn't work. However, I also downloaded from net so called a tif image that also didn't work. Does that mean they are not actually tiff?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [BitmapDecoder.Create()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615982(v=vs.110).aspx) This allows you to read stream type of any image

```
using (Stream stream = new FileStream(filepath,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read,FileShare.Read))
        {
            BitmapDecoder decoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache, BitmapCacheOption.None);

            BitmapSource bitmapsource = decoder.Frames[0];
        }
```